# using prerequisites in proper order

Tags: bash, makefile

How do I get make to generate a list of prerequisites in numerical order? I want to do something like this:

```
cat file1 file2 file10 file11 file21 | script
```

When I try this in a bash shell and in the Makefile:

```
cat file* | script
```

the files are used in the order file10 file11 file1 file21 file2
which is not what I want. In bash I can force the issue like this:

```
cat file{[0-9],[0-9][0-9]}
```

and similar tricks. But I do not know how to get make to recognize these wildcard options and I get many errors when I try to put variations of this in my Makefile:

```
target: file{[0-9],[0-9][0-9]}
        cat $^ | script
```

Obviously I do not want to list each file individually, I have shown only a few as an example, there are hundreds, and yes, there are gaps. So how do I get a nice make recipe that will use my files nicely in numerical order? (I could rename all the files from [digit] to 0[digit], but that seems like wimping out and avoiding the issue!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
# mkdir test
# cd test
# touch test{a,b}{9..11}.txt
# echo *
testa10.txt testa11.txt testa9.txt testb10.txt testb11.txt testb9.txt
# echo $(ls -v *)
testa9.txt testa10.txt testa11.txt testb9.txt testb10.txt testb11.txt
# echo testa*
testa10.txt testa11.txt testa9.txt
# echo $(ls -v testa*)
testa9.txt testa10.txt testa11.txt
```

Comment: Oh dear. There I thought I was a hotshot shell scripter and I have never been aware of ls -v. I am ashamed! This is a very useful ls option to know. This incident highlights the importance of READING THE MAN PAGES!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

inside your makefile. Other options seem a little too complicated for me (`($sort ...)` doesn't handle numeric comparisons).

Comment: I can get this to  work: SHELL=/bin/bash  files=$(shell echo file{[0-9],[0-9][0-9]}) target: $(files) cat $^ | script. Thanks!

Comment: It's supposed to be used with the target commands: try `target:`, `<Tab>echo $$0` and it should print `/bin/bash'

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but using:

```
cat file? file?? file??? | script    # add more file?'s as necessary
```

will achieve the effect you're looking for.

(*And as a bonus it makes it look like your command is getting increasingly desperate for input.*)

Comment: This would work if it did not also scoop up fileA, fileB and filedat, which are also present but not to be included.